Tag info text misleading: "All registered users may propose new tag wikis", yet no button shown to propose
When going to a tag's info page, I get shown an orange info box that states:

There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its usage.
All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
(Note that if you have less than 20000 reputation, your tag wiki will be peer reviewed before it is published.)

Yet, the page shows no way of how to propose new tag wikis. There's no button shown to me whatsoever.

This is confusing and can hardly be intended. There should either be a button on this page that leads directly to the tag wiki edit form, or the last two paragraphs should be removed.
One thing I found that works to create tag wikis is to manually navigate to the following URL:
https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/hyperterminal

(replace hyperterminal with the tag whose wiki you'd like to create)
This post is similar but not entirely identical to this meta question: Is the current way of creating a new tag wiki intended? The difference here is that I include the info box text.
In any case, the "All registered users may propose new tag wikis" text is wrong, as users with 5+ pending tag edits cannot propose new tag edits as explained in Pending limit for wiki tag edits.

"In any case, the "All registered users may propose new tag wikis" text is wrong, as users with 5+ pending tag edits cannot propose new tag edits as explained in Pending limit for wiki tag edits." - those aren't mutually exclusive. We also say "anyone can edit posts", but if you have <2k, you're subject to the suggested edits queue not being full, and anyone suspended can't edit either. Other very specific restrictions don't make the statement fundamentally false

This sounds more like a [[meta-tag:bug]] than a [[meta-tag:discussion]]. I can't see the edit button on my sock puppet and that has no pending edits. I can see it fine as me.

@ThomA The edit queue is probably full again

I hadn't considered that >_<

But if the queue was full - should I be able to see the edit form when I go to https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/hyperterminal ? I do get the form.

@Zoe-Savethedatadump Thanks for sharing extra exceptions besides having 5+ edits. Shouldn't exceptions that are frequently be encountered be listed there? I disagree that specific restrictions don't make a general statement false. A general statement without qualifications is expected to be generally true.

I'll argue we don't need to change the docs; the buttons just need to not disappear and signal exactly what the problem is. This has been previously requested and not done anything about.
